# Why do closed or on hold questions appear on the homepage?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, homepage, bump

I only go through the home page to find interesting questions and now I wonder why questions which are not open appear if there is any activity there.

I'm talking about questions which have [on hold] [duplicate] [closed] in their titles..

What's the point of showing them? As of now, searching for `[duplicate]` gave me three questions in the list, which is of no use right?

Comment: These questions may have been edited, which bumps them to the top of the list. This way, if they have been edited, they can be re-viewed and possibly reopened.

Comment: @Kendra got it.. Gonna delete this question... soon

Comment: You don't necessarily need to delete it. You had a legitimate question. I honestly wouldn't have known it if I hadn't been on Meta a lot recently.

Comment: @Kendra: Your first comment sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Ellesedil I was debating putting it as an answer, and not sure. I will. Thanks.

Comment: @Kendra while that's true, I think one can make an argument that since they automatically go into the reopen-queue when edited they shouldn't clutter up the home page.

Comment: @Jack Then make that argument. It's a viable one. It's just not what was asked here.

Comment: @Kendra that's what I initially assumed the OP's question actually was (since the have sufficient rep to have access to the review queues).

Comment: @Jack I can indeed see where you got that. A valid interpretation. (I didn't bother to look at the rep until you said that.) You could probably still make a feature-request of it. Then again, there might be people who would vote to reopen but don't bother with the reopen queue. So it would be useful in the regards of they may see it on the homepage and not use the queues.

Comment: @Kendra True, It isn't something that particularly bothers me (or at least not enough to make a feature request). I just thought that is what the OP was asking, but being that they agreed with you I guess that isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

These questions most likely have been edited, which bumps them to the top of the list. This way, they can be re-viewed and possibly reopened.